# constructor calling in array creation

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] a=new int[4];
```

i think when the array is created ..there will be 
the constructor calling (assigning elements to default values)
if i am correct..where is that constructor..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is no such thing. Primitive array elements are initialized to the default primitive value (`0` for `int`). Object array elements are initialized to `null`.

You can use `java.util.Arrays.fill(array, defaultElementValue)` to fill an array after you create it.

To quote the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#46168)

> An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10) or an array initializer (§10.6).

If you use an initializer, then the values are assigned. `int[] ar = new int[] {1,2,3}`

If you are using an array creation expression (as in your example), then ([JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#96595)):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or **array component** is initialized with a default value when it is created

Comment: then where they get default values ..directly by the jvm?

Comment: @saravanan didn't [ **this** ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873673/where-instance-variables-get-initialized/4873697#4873697) answer

Comment: @Bozho: thanks for your answer ..i have another doubt ..why we can't assign index value in anonymous array creation int[] ar = new int[] {1,2,3}....

Comment: what do you mean "index value" ?

Comment: because it is implied by the number of elements you specify in the initializer?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no such constructor. There is a dedicated *opcode* `newarray` in the java bytecode which is called in order to create arrays.

For instance this is the disassembled code for this instruction `int[] a = new int[4];`

```
0:  iconst_4      // loads the int const 4 onto the stack
1:  newarray int  // instantiate a new array of int 
3:  astore_1      // store the reference to the array into local variable 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From a conceptual level, you could see the array creation as a *array constructor*, but there is no way for a programmer to customize the constructor, as array types have no source code, and thus can't have any constructors (or methods, by the way).

See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910027/what-is-inside-code-for-array-length-in-java/4910894#4910894) for a conceptual view of arrays.

Actually, creating arrays is a primitive operation of the Java VM.